# how to close mat calendary using tab , close calendar when tab is pressed twice

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

when I press tab it opens the calendar but when I press tab again it should be close , the tab method or event no longer works when the calendar is opened unless I press escape , is there a way to these guys ? Thank you.

this is the only solution I know to set the focus back to the calendar

#screenshot

[image]

#ts code

```
 <div fxLayout="row" style="max-width: 100px;">
                        <input [readonly]="true" (click)="openPicker(pickerTargetDate);" 
                            [(ngModel)]="data.targetDate" 
                             appFocusOnLoad
                            (focus)="pickerTargetDate.open()" 
                            (keydown.Tab)="onEditTableInputsKeydownTab(i, 'actualProjectedDate')" 
                            matInput
                            [matDatepicker]="pickerTargetDate"
                            (dateChange)="dateChange(data,'parent','targetDate')" >
                        <mat-datepicker #pickerTargetDate></mat-datepicker>
                        <span *ngIf="data.targetDate && data.isRequired" (click)="openPicker(pickerTargetDate);"
                            style="font-size: 20px;padding-top: 4px;margin-right:5px;">
                            calendar_today
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

#Ts code

```
onEditKeydownTab(index, columnName: string) {
    this.editTable(index, columnName)
  }
 editTable(index:number,columnName: string , ) {
    this.indexEditing=index;
    this.selectedCell = columnName;
  }
```

Comment: You should be able to close the calendar by selecting a date, or tabbing through all elements. you could try tabIndex -1 on the items, but wouldn't you render the keyboard navigation useless then? I mean you do it for accessibility, a calendar where you cannot select a date seems useless to me.  I cannot try it those the comment.

Comment: cause my calendar are on different table cells , for if in cell 1 the user did not select a date he will just press tab and will close the current opened calendar and it will jump to the next cell , but right now I cant close it with a tab